# toggle buttons off regardless of state

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to toggle all buttons off regardless of the state they are currently in?

For example, I want to set all buttons to off...

```
$('.btn').each(function () {
//something here to turn off all buttons
$(this).off;
});
```

Comment: what kind of buttons you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about just

```
$('.btn').off('click');
```

or whatever event handler you're trying to remove ?

EDIT:

to remove classes and state :

```
$('.btn').blur().removeClass('active, disabled');
```

Comment: that's my question what is the event handler?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by "off", the jQuery `off()` method removes event handlers set with `on()` ?

Comment: it's not click, I just confirmed.

Comment: I mean "untoggled", not pressed, unselected

Comment: Then you're probably trying to remove a class from the elements

Comment: I'd buy that, how do you remove the class active or on?